# SQL Developer: Load Data Date error

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.03. I am trying to upload an Excel file to an Oracle data table. I am getting an error for the date. The column in the database is a timestamp and I don't know what to put into the date format for the 'Data Load Wizard'. If I use the following format (dd-mom-yy hh.mi.ss), SQL Developer will show the following error:

```
--Insert failed for row  1 TIMESTAMP_COLUMN GDK-05047: A day of the month must be between 1 and the last day of the month.
--Row 1
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, TIMESTAMP_COLUMN) VALUES ('Some Text','Some Text','Some more text',to_timestamp('40604.0', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss'));
```

The default number format IN EXCEL is: 40604.0
Which if you change the cell to a short date format you will get: 3/2/2011

I am trying to figure out what 'Format' I need to put into the FORMAT section of the 'DATA Load Wizard' that will accept the date format that is in EXCEL and upload it to Oracle as a TIMESTAMP.

[image]

Comment: if you insert **INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, TIMESTAMP_COLUMN) VALUES ('Some Text','Some Text','Some more text', '12-08-88 00.00.00');** does it give you an error?

Comment: @p0rter I would think that would work, but the date in the Excel file is in this format: 40604.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel "zero" date is January 0 (yes, zero), 1900.  Since Oracle can't handle a "zero" day in a month you need to subtract 1 from the Excel value; thus the following should get you close to what you want:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1900 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP) +
           NUMTODSINTERVAL(41017.6361109954 - 1, 'DAY')
  FROM DUAL
```

As far as "how to import it" goes, there's no Oracle date format that I'm aware of to do this.  The easiest thing would be to import the value into a NUMBER column and then run a script to do the date conversion.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing today, and 'fixed' this two ways.  The second way probably seems too complex, but it might help someone if they have a hard time automating the formatting of dates to look like Oracle's standard dd-mmm-yy.

1. Format the date columns in Excel as dd-mmm-yy and import directly into the table.

   - Highlight the column(s)
   - Choose "More Number Formats" where the existing format is (In Excel 2010, it says General in a dropbox on the Home tab
   - Select the last entry "Custom" in the Category box
   - Manually enter dd-mmm-yy in the Type: box
2. Format the date columns in Excel as mm/dd/yy, import the table in as text, write a manual insert statement from the temp text table using `TO_DATE(date_field,'MM/DD/YYYY')`

   - Highlight the column(s)
   - Choose "More Number Formats" where the existing format is (In Excel 2010, it says General in a dropbox on the Home tab
   - Select the "Date" entry in the Category box
   - Choose "03/14/01" from the list

Answer (score 0):

yeah and that's the problem.

"**A day of the month must be between 1 and the last day of the month.**"

**1)** how are these decimals created?

**2)** is this "**04-06-2004**" ? or are these seconds from 1970?

you need to add more detail about this number format!